# Javascript - `this` binding in call back with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the below piece of code, when `sayAysncHi()` is called on `gs` object, what is `this` bound to ? My understanding is that `this` is bound to the thing to the left of the dot (`.`) operator which in this case should be the `GreetingService` object `gs`. However in this case the `this.name` inside the `sayAsyncHi` fn is coming in a `undefined` - why is this so?

```
// file greeting_service.js
function GreetingService(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sayHi = function () {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(`Hi ${this.name}!`);
  }
  this.sayAsyncHi = function () {
    setTimeout(function (params) {
      console.log(this);
      console.log(`Hi ${this.name}!`);
    },2000);
  }
  this.sayBye = function () {
    console.log(`Bye ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

var gs = new GreetingService('Jon');
gs.sayHi(); // Hello Jon!
gs.sayAsyncHi(); // Hello undefined!
```

Output on running `node greeting_service.js` ( nodejs 6)

```
GreetingService {
  name: 'Jon',
  sayHi: [Function],
  sayAsyncHi: [Function],
  sayBye: [Function] }
Hi Jon!

Timeout {
  _called: true,
  _idleTimeout: 2000,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idleStart: 389,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _repeat: null }
Hi undefined!
```

PS: with ES6 Arrow function the binding is correct as expected for the above Async call

Comment: `() => {} ~= function(){}.bind(this)`

Comment: Yes, `this` is `gs` in `sayAsyncHi`. But in the timout you have another function, which has another `this`.

Comment: Closure functions created with 'function' keyword creates own scope. So 'setTimeout(function()...{}) creates new scope. You can fix by using ES6 arraw functions or use '.bind(this)' to give your scope.

Comment: @Oriol - regarding the another `this` inside the function in setTimeout, what is the value of `this` really in the above case ?

Comment: @user3206440 It's the window in browsers. I don't know in node, maybe the <Timeout> instance that will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

A small fix (I added `.bind(this)`):

```
this.sayAsyncHi = function () {
  setTimeout(function (params) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(`Hi ${this.name}!`);
  }.bind(this), 2000);
}
```

**EDIT**

A bit of explanation: in `sayAsyncHi`, you'll find the `this` variable has the value you expect. But the function you pass to `setTimeout` isn't bound to any value of `this`. You need to explicitly bind it if you want a specific value.

Comment: Async variant

    this.sayAsyncHi = function () {
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function (params) {
        console.log(self);
        console.log(`Hi ${self.name}!`);
      }, 2000);
    }